# Pass in variable instance from another method

Tags: c#, parameters, parameter-passing

I have an on execute method that has variable "item". I need to pass that variable to my other method "IsStatusChangeValid"

Below is what I currently have, but so far its not working. I looked at some related questions on stack overflow such as [Accessing Variables From Another Method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18895408/accessing-variables-from-another-method)
and looked at some parameter passing tutorials/examples online such as
[Parameter Passing in C#](http://www.yoda.arachsys.com/csharp/parameters.html)
but I have been unable to apply the information properly.

```
protected override CommandResult OnExecute()
{
    var item = ItemViews.ItemGet(itemId);

    if (IsStatusChangeValid())
    { 
        ...
    }
    else
    { 
        ... 
    }
}

public bool IsStatusChangeValid(item)
{
    // ONLY IF SET EXISTS
    if (item.ItemSets.Count > 0)
    {
        // CHECK IF ITEM STATUS IS CHANGED TO "CLOSED-VOIDED"
        if (newDescription.Equals("Closed-Voided"))
        {
            // IF THERE ARE NON-VOIDED SETS, DO NOT ALLOW THE STATUS CHANGE
            if (item.ItemSets.Any(p => p.SetStatusID != SetStatusIDConstants.Voided))
            {
                return false;
            }
        }
    }
    return true;
}
```

Comment: How are you trying to call the second method? from with inside the `OnExecute` method? What did you try that didn't work (and why didn't it work)?

Comment: Sayse: I have an if statement in OnExecute that does `if (IsStatusChangeValid) {do work} else {stop and post warning}` I've tried `IsStatusChangeValid(item)` and `IsStatusChangeValid(ItemViews item)` and `IsStatusChangeValid(Item item)` The first one throws an error under item. The second two throw errors from within the `IsStatusChangeValid` method.

Comment: And how have you tried to use it? Your second link has a fairly decent example under Value parameters

Comment: sorry. just updated that previous comment with what I have tried.

Comment: `IsStatusChangeValid(item)` is correct, what error did you get

Comment: `the type or namespace name 'item' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)`

Comment: Could you please update your question to include exactly what code it was that you tried when trying to use `IsStatusChangeValid(item)`?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/76068/discussion-between-atlasbowler-and-sayse).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are two mistakes you made in your code

1. The declaration of the method

You must define what type a parameter is

```
public bool IsStatusChangeValid(Item item)
```

2. You must pass in an item into the call of the method

```
if(IsStatusChangeValid(item))
```

Comment: and no more errors. Thank you for your assistance. You've been very helpful.

Comment: @AtlasBowler - No worries, I've just seen that [MSDN has a page on passing parameters](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0f66670z.aspx) that you may find more useful